# ASP.NET MVC 5 user confirmation and store data in temp storage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a method in the controller that deals with certain data taken from the user, and I need to take user confirmation in a specific situation, so it should go from controller to view to display popup window conformation.

Then if the user agrees I have to go back to the controller and continue executing in another method with the same data, the problem is how can I go to the view and back to the controller without losing the data? is there any other way to take user confirmation without going to view?

Or is there a way to store the data (list) in temporary storage? (I can't store the data in my database)

Comment: can't you do an ajax call?

Comment: Keep the data in a `Session` variable. Something like `Session["myData"]=data`. Then in your next action, you can retrieve this based on the `myData` key and process your data as required. Once the cycle is completed, you can remove this session variable: `Session.Remove("myData")`;

Answer (score 0):

You can either use ViewBag or TempData based on your use case. The topic comes under the category of "Session and state management" in ASP.NET.

Example of using ViewBag

**Controller**

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Foo";
        return View();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @ViewBag.Message
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Example of using TempData

**Controller**

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        TempData["foo"] = "bar";

        return View();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@TempData["foo"]
```

TempData value will expire as soon as you read it. You've to call *TempData.Keep("foo")* if you want to persist the value.

Here you can read more on [Session and state management in ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state)